# Cesàro Sum of Tangent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ergodic-theory

Can you proof or disprove the following? $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac {\tan1+\tan 2+\cdots+\tan n}{n})=0$.  Is there any ergodic type theorem that can come to help?

Comment: Perhaps it's helpful : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650403/which-methods-different-than-the-natural-one-can-one-devise-to-confirm-that-the

Comment: @ Julien.I need to read through that carefully.In fact this came up as I was thinking of [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470527/does-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tan-nn2-converge/658898#658898)

Comment: So...look at : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159438/prove-the-convergence-divergence-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac-tank