# Help with Series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me prove that the following series $S$ converges:

$$S=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^2|\sin(m)|}$$

I would appreciate any help in constructing a simple proof.

Comment: I am wrong and sorry for it.

Comment: I believe it is hard, and there was a similar question with tangent but I can't find it..

Comment: I think it may be an open problem, see:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown

Comment: @user901823 fantastic lol