# Innocent looking open problems in real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, big-list, open-problem

Are there any apparently easy problems or conjectures in basic real analysis (that is, calculus) that are still open? By apparently easy, I mean: so much so, that, if it was for the statement alone, they could be part of a calculus book for undergraduates?

Comment: [Asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537480/open-problems-in-real-analysis) (but only one answer)

Comment: @Winther Thank you, but my question is more specific than that.

Comment: I do not know how low-level you're looking for, but I remember learning about the Invariant subspace problem and thinking it was very simple to understand.


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for questions marked as [open-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/open-problem) or [open-problem-list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/open-problems-list) on mathoverflow. I guess you will find some open problems there.

Here a list of some open questions i have found there:

- [Convergence of a series](https://mathoverflow.net/a/100351/56668) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown)
- [Gourevitch's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/a/100290/56668)
- [Cover of the unit square by rectangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles)
- ...