# Is analysis an area of maths we understand fully, or are there many open questions?

Tags: analysis

I apologise for my naivety, and just want to clarify I know very little about analysis, except it involves the fundamental proofs of calculus. That being said, analysis seems like an area that would be interesting to research if I ever got to that stage, so was wondering if there are many open questions left in analysis, and if so, what would be an example?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are many open questions left.

Comment: Is there an example that you could give, or do they not have simple names?

Comment: See [Innocent looking open problems ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1095743/13130) *AND* [Are there any series ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20555/13130) *AND* the paper [*Real Analysis in Computer Science: A collection of Open Problems*](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/openprobsmerged.pdf) *AND* "A fixed point theorem for differentials?" in [this blog post](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/two-very-early-problems-a-simple-solution-and-a-new-problem/) *AND* [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22open+problems+in+complex+analysis%22).

Comment: Did you read the Wikipdia article about unsolved problems in mathematics ? A major problem in analysis that is still quite open is determining whether a given number is rational. Unknown examples include the Euler-Mascheroni-constant, $\ e+\pi\ $ and $\ e\cdot \pi\ $

Comment: You would probably get a much clearer understanding of your own question after a first year graduate course in analysis which goes deeper into the topic beyond just fundamental proofs in calculus. Also, this would be a good investment of your time in preparation for *any* topic of mathematical research. That's why a one year course in analysis is required for every mathematics graduate program on the planet.

Comment: @Peter: The problems you mentioned are not really from analysis, but would probably fall under the purview of number theory, probably [MSC2010 classification](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/pdfs/classifications2010.pdf) **11J72** (**11**: *Number Theory*; **11Jxx**: *Diophantine approximation, transcendental number theory*; **11J72**: *Irrationality; linear independence over a field*). However, it's a very good bet that a lot of hard-core analysis will be involved in any proofs of these results that might eventually be discovered.

Comment: Why only analysis is interesting for you?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I love most areas of maths, but calculus is something I find the most intuitive to understand I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If we are dealing with headings as broad as "analysis" then this includes analysis of ordinary and partial differential equations (ODE and PDE) which is a huge, huge part of mathematics. The study of PDE might be the single biggest field of mathematics if there were a way of measuring such a thing.