# For what values of $k>1$ does $\sum_{n>1} 1/(n^k\sin(n))$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For what values of $k>1$ does $\sum_{n>1} 1/(n^k\sin(n))$ converge?

Comment: That depends on the irrationality measure of $\pi$ and I believe is an open problem.

Comment: Due to the work of Viola and Rhin, it is convergent for any $k\geq 8$, but that is probably very far from being the optimal bound.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown