# Convergence of below series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what $k \geq1 $, will the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(n^k|sin(n)|)$ converge?

Comment: Definitely not for $k=1$.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that large values of the summand correspond to numerators of good rational approximations to $\pi$, but we don't have a very good handle on irrationality measures for $\pi$. 
See [this paper of Alekseyev](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5100v1.pdf).