# To check whether given sequence is convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the sequence $$a(n)=\frac{\sin{(3^{n})}}{\sin{(5^{n})}}$$ convergent or divergent? As $n$ tends to $\infty$, I am not getting which limit formula to apply.

Any hint?

Comment: there is no Limit (infinity)

Comment: the formula above

Comment: both function do not have limits

Comment: But both functions are bounded by 1 so I am not satisfied yet .

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You could say the same about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(3^n)}{\sin(3^n)}$, but in that case the limit is clearly $1$.

Comment: I am puzzled by this question, it looks more like a number-theoretic question about irrationality of numbers of type $\frac{3^n}{\pi}$ (or $\frac{5^n}{\pi}$) than a calculus question. I cannot answer it personally. Out of curiosity, what is the context where you came up with this question?

Comment: Reminds me of [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/) although this question might be easier to resolve(?).

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen..thanks for the link..

Comment: @user8734617 I cannot solve it either, I think. While [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) that the numbers you mention are irrational, that is not enough.

Comment: What book (author(s), title)?

Comment: It's not reference book..just local maths book by one publication..

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I know they are irrational, but what I really meant is that any proof may draw from the theory of Diophantine approximations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) which is used to measure how 'close' to rational are irrational numbers. Thus I wonder if this post merits cross-posting to MathOverflow.