# Is there any function whose limit at $x_0$ is unknown?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, open-problem

I would like to know if there is any non trivial function $f(x)$ and a $x_0$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\ x_0} f(x)$$
is currently not known, with $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$.
An example of a "trivial" function is $A(x)$ where $A(x)$ denotes the number of perfect numbers not greater than $x$. It is an open problem to find the value of  $\lim_{x\to\infty} A(x)$, since we don't know if there are infinitely many perfect numbers.
I would prefer a limit which can be recognized by a high school student.

Comment: A slightly different example would be a function counting the integers $<x$ for which the sequence in the Collatz conjecture doesn't end at $1$ (I call it slight different because wee don't know if any such integer exist, i.e. whether the function ever becomes $\neq 0$, where we know 50 perfect numbers). But that is probably also trivial, but you haven't given us a definition of trivial that is actually workable.

Comment: The value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}R(n,n)^{\frac1n}$$ where $R(n,n)$ is a so-called [Ramsey number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html) is unknown. It is known that the limit (if it exists) lies in the interval $[\sqrt2,4].$

Comment: It is unknown whether $1/(n^2\sin n)$ converges as $n \to \infty$ (see [Are there any series whose convergence is unknown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown)). Not sure if it is duplicate since it asks for series, but one of the answer gives this sequence as an example, so in a sense...

Answer (score 2):

[Brun's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem) states that the sum of reciprocals of twin primes is convergent, but there is no other known expression for the limit.