# A series whose convergence is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

It was claimed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2387782/446262) that the convergence of the series$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)-1}{n^{1/2}\log^3 n}\tag1$$(where $\Lambda$ is the [Von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)) is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis. Is this true? That post provided a link to the Wikipedia article about the Von Mangoldt function, which does *not* mention this. Also, [this page](https://aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/95a/) about the Von Mangoldt function in the context of the Riemann hypothesis makes no mention to that.

If it is true that the convergence of the series $(1)$ is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis, then I would like to have a reference for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claymath official [description](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/official_problem_description.pdf) of the Riemann hypothesis claims the RH is true iff $\pi(x) = Li(x)+O(x^{1/2}\log x)$ so $\psi(x) = x+O(x^{1/2}\log^2 x)$ and I have been quite sloppy in that it implies the RH is true iff $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)-1}{n^{1/2}\log^{\color{red}{3+\epsilon}} n} < \infty\tag{1}$$

as with partial summation $$\sum_{n \le x} (\Lambda(n)-1) \frac{1}{n^{1/2}\log^{a} n}=\frac{\psi(x)-x}{x^{1/2}\log^a x}+\sum_{n \le x-1} (\psi(n)-n)O(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}\log^a n})\\ = O(\log^{2-a}(x))+\sum_{n \le x} O(\frac{1}{n\log^{a-2} n})$$

---

The point is to show an effective [explicit formula](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main5.pdf) (p.28) $$\psi(x) =\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)= x - \sum_{|\Im(\rho)| \le T} \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}+O(\frac{x\log^2 x}{T})=x - \sum_{k\le K} 2\Re(\frac{x^{\rho_k}}{\rho_k})+O(\frac{x\log^2 x}{K/\log K})$$
where $K = N(T)$ and the density of zeros gives $K \sim C T \log T,T \sim c K/\log K$,$\Im(\rho_k) \sim c k/\log k$.

In this form, under the RH, with $K = x^{1/2}$ it yields
$$\psi(x) =x +O(x^{1/2}\log^{2+\delta})$$

Plotting those things indicates the series may converge very slowly with $\epsilon = 0$ and it is quite certain (under the RH) it converges with $\epsilon = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is by reading Terry Tao's post ["The Riemann hypothesis in various settings"](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/the-riemann-hypothesis-in-various-settings/)

Comment: so (if we can't find a cancellation in the phases of the explicit formula) we really need $\log^{3+\epsilon} n$ instead of $\log^3 n$