# Can we always know whether an infinite series converges or diverges, if we are summing over an elementary expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, elementary-functions

Just like the question stated, can we always determine the convergence of an infinite sum of an elementary function?

For example, given some elementary function f(n) can we determine if the sum will converge or diverge for any elementary function?

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$

Comment: Is it a series of numbers or functions? As for funtions, there are differences between point-to-point convergence and uniform convergence, both of which are easy to determine.

Comment: @rushusuixing A series of functions, such as summing over (1/3n)

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you mean a series or a series of function? if so what type of convergence?

Comment: @Craftinators Your example is not a series of functions...What I mean is somthing like $f(x)=\sum_{n=1]^\infty \frac{1}{n}sin(nx).$

Comment: @rushusuixing I edited the question, hopefully its clearer now?

Comment: It is a well-known result that the convergence of the series is consistent with $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$.

Comment: Ah, thats exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are some simple-seeming series whose convergence or divergence is unknown.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/are-there-any-series-whose-convergence-is-unknown

Comment: @rushusuixing That's only the case for monotone $f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $f(n) = \frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2(n)}$, which if you consider $\sin$ to be elementary is an elementary function.

The convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, the [Flint Hills](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html) series is an open problem.

Comment: I see that Jair Taylor beat me to it in the comments without me realising. Hopefully posting a similar answer to his comment isn't considered rude.

Comment: Not rude, thank you for posting :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help everyone

Answer (score 1):

First condition $f(n)$ must converge to $0$ for $n$ to $\infty$. 2. $f(n+1)/f(n) <1$ for $n$ to $\infty$
or root criterium.
look up in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests